# if i rename the namespace of an app will the approved open graph action need resubmitting

Tags: namespaces, action, facebook-opengraph, rename

we need to rename one of our apps which already have open graph action approved, if we rename the namespace of the app will the approved open graph action need resubmitting?

Cheers

Brett

Answer (score 0):

I guess yes, since facebook has clearly mentioned that -

> Make sure you are using the right namespace for your API calls. Remember that an application namespace cannot be modified once set.

Ref: [OG Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/#debug)